# extrapolating object state based on updates

Tags: client-server, state

I have a networked multi-user collaborative application. To maintain a consistent virtual world, I send updates for objects from a master peer to a guest peer. The update state contains

x,y,z  coordinates of object center and his rotation matrix(CHAI3d api used a 3x3 matrix) with 30Hz frequency.

I want to reduce this update rate and want to send with a reduced update rate. I want a predictor on both peers. When the predicted value is outside, say a error value of 10% in comparison to  master peers objects original state the master peer triggers a state update.

Now for position I used velocity,position updates so that the guest peer can extrapolate position.

Like velocity for position what parameter should I use for rotation extrapolition?

Answer (score 1):

Angular velocity would seem the obvious choice based on what you're already doing. But unless the objects will be moving and turning with a constant velocity, acceleration on both counts might be a better predictor for any given velocity.